# Python Data Model Document : an unbound user-defined method object and a class method object

Tags: python, oop, object, methods, python-datamodel

In **Data Model** of the reference, writer spent lots of effort explaining how **User-defined methods** are created and operated:(See http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy and roll down)

> User-defined method objects may be created when getting an attribute
>   of a class (perhaps via an in- stance of that class), **if that
>   attribute is a user-defined function object, an unbound user-defined
>   method object, or a class method object.** When the attribute is a
>   user-defined method object, a new method object is only created if the
>   class from which it is being retrieved is the same as, or a derived
>   class of, the class stored in the original method object; otherwise,
>   the original method object is used as it is.

So what's the difference between **an unbound user-defined method object** and **a class method object**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the "user" point of view, a class method in Python is a method that receives its class as its first parameter - unlike "ordinary" methods which receive an instance of the class as its first parameter - which by convention is called `self`.

If you retrieve an "ordinary" method from a class, instead of from an instace of that class, you get an "unbound method" - i.e. an object that is a wrapper around a function, but that does not automatically adds either the class itself, nor any instance as the first parameter when it is called. Threfore if you are to call the "unbound method" you have to manually pass an instance of its class as its first parameter.

If you manually call a class method, on the other hand, the class is filled in as the first parameter for you:

```
>>> class A(object):
...   def b(self):
...      pass
...   @classmethod
...   def c(cls):
...      pass
... 
>>> A.b
<unbound method A.b>
>>> A.c
<bound method type.c of <class '__main__.A'>>
>>> A.c()
>>> A.b()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method b() must be called with A instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
>>>
```

Under the hood what goes is more or less like this - with "new style classes":

When one defines a class body, the methods are just ordinary functions - when the class body is over, Python calls the class's metaclass (which ordinarily is the builtin `type` ) - and pass to it as parameters the name, base classes, and class body dictionary.  This call yields a class - which in Python is, an object which is a class, since everything is an object.

Now, Python has some nifty ways of customizing attribute access - the so called "descriptors". A descriptor is any object that defines a method named `__get__` (or `__set__` or `__del__` but we don't care about those here). When one access an attribute of a class or object in Python, the object referred by that attribute is returned - except if it is a class attribute, and the object is a descriptor. In that case, instead of returning the object itself, Python calls the  `__get__` method on that object, and returns its results instead. For example, the `property` built-in is just a class that implements both `__set__`, `__get__` and `__del__` as appropriate.

Now, what happens when the attribute is retrieved, is that any function (or class method or unbound method, as the data model states) on its body, does have a `__get__` method, which makes it a descriptor. Basically, a descriptor that at each attribute access to retrieve the object named as the function as it is defined on the function body, creates a new object around that function - an object that when called  will have the first parameter automatically filled in - which is to say, a `method`.

Ex.:

```
>>> class B(object):
...    def c(self):
...      pass
...    print c
... 
<function c at 0x1927398>
>>> print B.c
<unbound method B.c>
>>> b = B()
>>> b.c
<bound method B.c of <__main__.B object at 0x1930a10>
```

If you want to retrieve the function object, without conversion to  a method object, you can do so through the class's `__dict__` attribute, which does not trigger the descriptor:

```
>>> B.__dict__["c"]
<function c at 0x1927398>
>>> B.__dict__["c"].__get__
<method-wrapper '__get__' of function object at 0x1927398>
>>> B.__dict__["c"].__get__(b, B)
<bound method B.c of <__main__.B object at 0x1930a10>>
>>> B.__dict__["c"].__get__(None, B)
<unbound method B.c>
```

As for "class methods", these are just different type of objects, which are explicitly decorated with the builtin `classmethod` - The object it returns when its `__get__` is called is a wrapper around the original function that will fill in the `cls` as the first parameter on call.

Comment: so a bound/unbound user-defined method is "Method of an instance", while a classmethod is "Method of an class, right?

Comment: In other words, if you try call unbound method directly from class you  are get exception, and for call this method you must create object at first, and then call method "from" object. If you want call method directly from class you can use decorator @staticmethod

Comment: @Denis Well, when getting the attribute which is a method decorated with `@classmethod`, can we say that it is a bound method to the class?

Comment: Yes - it is then a classmethod, bound to the class.